# Access the table hidden inside an iframe using python and selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, iframe

I'm trying to access announcements table from this [web page](https://www2.asx.com.au/markets/trade-our-cash-market/todays-announcements). The table is in an iframe, the contents of which are not visible in the source when the page loads. The table only shows up in source if I do inspect element "twice". Once the table is visible I can execute the below javascript code via chrome console to access the table.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getElementsByTagName('section')[4].getElementsByTagName('article')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[2].getElementsByTagName('announcement_data')[0].getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')
```

However, I'm struggling to find a way to make the elements inside the iframe visible programmatically using python and selenium. I've tried to switch to the iframe but that has not helped.

```
seq = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
print("No of frames present in the web page are: ", len(seq))

iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
table = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getElementsByTagName('body')[0].getElementsByTagName('section')[4].getElementsByTagName('article')[0].getElementsByTagName('div')[2].getElementsByTagName('announcement_data')[0].getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');")
```

I get the following error if I try to run the above code in my jupyter notebook -

```
No of frames present in the web page are:  4

Error getting the length of the table: list index out of range
```

Any pointers to access the length and content of the table would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you just load the iframe's url into selenium? `https://www.asx.com.au/asx/v2/statistics/todayAnns.do`

Comment: Thank you @Hagai. That is why I love Stackoverflow. That did the trick! Now, how do I mark your comment as an answer to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to scrape the iframe url programmatically and then load that up as a new page in selenium.

`https://www.asx.com.au/asx/v2/statistics/todayAnns.do` is the url for the iframe.

To do it programmatically try something like this:

```
url = driver.find_element_by_class_name('external-form__iframe default').get_attribute("src")
driver.get(url)
```